# Recyclerview layout not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm facing an issue regarding `RecyclerView` in fragment.
I moved my `recyclerview` from `activity` to `fragment`.
After moving to fragment.
it shows error

> No adapter attached; skipping layout

Here is my code

```
public class LatestProperty extends Fragment {
    View customView;
    private List<PropertyInfo> propertyInfoList=new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PropertyAdapter propertyAdapter;
    View view;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String areaType;
    private String imagePath="abc";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.total_properties, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity(),R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);

        propertyAdapter=new PropertyAdapter(getActivity(),propertyInfoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);
        preparePropertyData();


        return view;
    }

public void preparePropertyData()
    {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Latest Properties...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        Config config=new Config();
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(new StringRequest(config.getLatestPropertyData
                , new Response.Listener<String>() {
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        String area=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("area");
                        area=area.replace("null","NA");
                        String Gallery=    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("gallery");
                        String[] dot=Gallery.split(";");
                        String stringPrice=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("price");
                        stringPrice=stringPrice.replace(",","").replace("null","0");
                        Long price=Long.parseLong(stringPrice);
                        String areaType=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("area_type").replace("null","");
                        PropertyInfo propertyInfo=new PropertyInfo(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"),jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("bed"),jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("bath"),area,areaType,jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("address"),jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("purpose"),withSuffix(price).toString(), imagePath+dot[0],jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                        propertyInfoList.add(propertyInfo);

                    }
                    propertyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                CookieBar.Build(getActivity()).setTitle("Oppss. :(").setMessage("Server Error..!").setBackgroundColor(R.color.cookieColor).show();
            }
        }));


    }
```

Here is Adapter Class

```
public PropertyAdapter(Context context,List<PropertyInfo> propertyInfoList) {
        this.mContext=context;
        this.propertyInfoList = propertyInfoList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recent_property_single_item, parent, false);


        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

Comment: check your getCount function in adapter. I hope its not default 0.

Comment: nope. my code works fine with nougat. but not working on others when i moved in fragment. now no error shows in logcat

Comment: Check with Layout Inspector whether your Recyclerview do not have 0 height or width.

Comment: its match parent & wrap content

Comment: Post your XML please

Comment: post the `Log` in `OnBindViewHolder` is  `value`  present or not

Comment: Also debug and see if your jsonArray length is not 0

Comment: Its not going into try

Comment: Not going into "try" or "catch"??

Comment: i mean adapter is not working. don't know why. i printed toast there in try working fine . i hard coded my values outside try then working fine but inside try, its not working although toast is printing inside try. . issue is i think with adapter

Comment: toast jsonArray length inside try

Comment: hardcoded values before try is working but not inside or after try (before catch)

Comment: i try to toasted jsonarray length but its show error
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x64

Comment: sorry i forgot to convert in string

Comment: length is printing : 100 as per my jsonArray its correct value

Answer (score 1):

> No adapter attached; skipping layout

Because your are Adding  data in your **`Arraylist`** after setting **`Adapter`** to Your **`Recyclerview`**  and  **also network operation take time for response**

> You need First add Data in Your **`propertyInfoList`** than set **`Adapter`** to Your **`RecyclerView`**

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    preparePropertyData();
    propertyAdapter=new PropertyAdapter(getActivity(),propertyInfoList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);
```

Comment: But hi is notify after adding data . In your code adapter is set before filling data because network operation take time for response

Comment: @Nilesh no error but not showing any thing in recyclerview.
my code works fine with nougat. but not working with lollipop and others.

Comment: @MuhammadSaad try this **`adapter.notifyItemInserted(propertyInfoList.size());`** and also check that your **`getItemCount`** must return **`propertyInfoList.size()`**

Comment: where to put notifyItemInserted? and getItemCount already propertyInfoList.size()

Comment: @MuhammadSaad before **`propertyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`**

Comment: @NileshRathod hard coded values are working. but not from database

Comment: @MuhammadSaad **network operation take time for response** just for test case set Your Adapter after adding data in your **`propertyInfoList`**

Comment: well i got my issue. its not going into try catch

Comment: ohh greate @MuhammadSaad enjoy codding

Comment: I'm confusing . if its not going into try then why its working on nougat

Comment: @MuhammadSaad i'm also confuse about that it happen some times happy to help you enjoy coddig

Comment: adapter is not working. don't know why. i hard coded my values outside try then working fine but inside try, its not working although toast is printing inside try.

Comment: @MuhammadSaad didn't know about it I'm also shocked anyway your problem solved happy codding

Comment: not working :D 
hardcoded values before try is working but not inside or after try (before catch)

Comment: @MuhammadSaad try to **`propertyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`** outside try catch

Comment: @MuhammadSaad can you share your json response

Comment: [
    {
        "id": 527,
        "user_id": 220,
        "approved_by_id": null,
        "title": "12 Marla House, Block F, Johar Town Lahore For Sale",
        "description": "<p><strong>Selling Price:</strong>&nbsp;2 Crore 40 Lac</p>\r\n<p><strong>About The Property:</strong><br />&bull; 4 Bedrooms<br />&bull; Attached Bathrooms<br />&bull; Drawing Room<br />&bull; Dining Room<br />&bull;"
     
    }]

Comment: i wrote short form of response . its too lengthy so

Comment: `propertyAdapter=new PropertyAdapter(getActivity(),propertyInfoList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);`
i wrote these lines after try and it again shows error.: ** No adapter attached skipping layout**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157999/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-muhammad-saad).

Answer (score 0):

When the Exception occurs for the `RecyclerView` items, have a look at your `MyAdapter` class and your related `ViewHolder` and check if you correctly get your `TextView` there.

Comment: my code works fine with nougat. but not working with lollipop and others.

Comment: To solve the problem, I firstly added the multidex support library in my build.gradle file:  Please use this link for more information.                                                                           https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: multidex? why? any reason?

Comment: When your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods, you encounter a build error that indicates your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture. Try adding compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'  in your manifest file

Comment: **Try adding compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'** in **`Build.Gradle`** @NiranjanReddy

Comment: Yaa sorry by mistake. You need to add in build.gradle. :)

Comment: @NiranjanReddy If it would have been multidex issue there would be crash but in this case he didn't mentioned about crash

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html    Refer this. You can figure it out.

Comment: not crashing.. was showing error . now no error but not working also

Comment: This link will help you bro. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: @NiranjanReddy there is no multidex issue so stop suggesting irrelevant solutions. If it would have been multidex issue then it would have worked on Lollipop.

Comment: Without refering the link, how can you answer to my question bro. That link contains answer for which he is looking. Let him figure out in that link.

Comment: @NiranjanReddy he is not looking answer for multidex issue he looking for issue wherein Recyclerview is not updated with the elements he had inserted. Refer to question once again and then suggest your answer.